# How do I put a subwindow within a subwindow?

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I am using NCurses to try and get the desired output:
[image: I am trying to put a blue box inside the white space]

However with the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
     WINDOW *white_space,*red_space,*blue_box;
     int maxx,maxy;

     initscr();
     start_color();
     init_pair(1,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_BLUE);
     init_pair(2,COLOR_RED,COLOR_WHITE);
     init_pair(3,COLOR_BLACK,COLOR_GREEN);
     init_pair(4,COLOR_RED,COLOR_RED);


     white_space = subwin(stdscr,10,76,6,2);
     red_space = subwin(stdscr,1,80,23,0);
     getmaxyx(white_space,maxy,maxx);
     blue_box = subwin(white_space,maxy-1,maxx-1,8,20);
     if(white_space == NULL)
     {
     addstr("Unable to create subwindow\n");
     endwin();
     return 1;
     }


     bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(1));
     addstr("Master window");
     wbkgd(white_space,COLOR_PAIR(2));
     mvwprintw(white_space, 0, 0, "%46s", "White space");
     wbkgd(blue_box,COLOR_PAIR(4));
     wbkgd(red_space,COLOR_PAIR(3));
     waddstr(red_space,"Alert area");
     wrefresh(white_space);
     wrefresh(stdscr);


     refresh();
     getch();

     endwin();
     return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:
[image]

Is it possible to create a subwindow within a subwindow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ncurses (any non-buggy version of curses) supports subwindows, as noted in the [manual](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html).

In the given example, there are a few problems noticed:

```
 white_space = subwin(stdscr,10,76,6,2);
 red_space = subwin(stdscr,1,80,23,0);
 getmaxyx(white_space,maxy,maxx);
 blue_box = subwin(white_space,maxy-1,maxx-1,8,20);
```

For instance:

- the initial size given to `white_space` does not take into account the actual screen-size (which could be narrower than 80 columns)
- the size asked for `blue_box` is only slightly smaller than `white_space`, but starts far enough to the right that the window could not (in 80 columns) be shown.  If so, no window is created.

There are several programs in [`ncurses-examples`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html) using `subwin` and the related `derwin`, which may be useful for comparison.